# Querying from the terminal doesn't print anything

Tags: command-line, prolog, swi-prolog

When ran in the command line, this

```
swipl -g "write(42)" -t "halt"
```

prints 42 to `STDOUT` as expected.

However, this

```
swipl -g "X = 42" -t "halt"
```

does not print anything, it simply returns.

How do I get it to print what it prints in the REPL (that is, `X = 42`)?

*Note: this is in a Windows terminal. Let me know if this actually works in a Linux terminal.*

Comment: Playing with `with_output_to/2` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: "*Prints 42 to STDOUT as expected.*" Nothing more? What about "true" or "yes"?

Comment: @repeat it doesn't print true, which is probably the exact same problem that happens when it doesn't print `X = 42`. basically it seems that everything printed explicitely to STDOUT is indeed printed, but everything "printed by the REPL" isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As expected, `X = 42` by itself produces **no output whatsoever**, because `(=)/2` is a completely pure predicate that does not yield any side effects by itself. This is the case on Window, OSX and all other operating systems.

Even if there were a way to obtain and redirect the toplevel output itself, the fact remains that the SWI toplevel is subject to change and you cannot rely on future versions to behave in the same way as it does now. Long term, you will likely be better off to roll **your own toplevel** and produce exactly the output you want.

It is not so hard to roll your own toplevel. The trick is mainly to use the `variable_names/1` option when reading terms, so that you can keep track of the variable **names** that you want to show in answers. Here is a *very simplistic* start:

```
repl :-
        read_line_to_codes(current_input, Codes),
        read_term_from_codes(Codes, Term, [variable_names(NameVars)]),
        call(Term),
        report_bindings(NameVars).
repl :- repl.

report_bindings(NameVars) :-
        phrase(bindings(NameVars), Bs),
        format("~s", [Bs]).

bindings([])           --> [].
bindings([E])          --> name_var(E).
bindings([E1,E2|Rest]) --> name_var(E1), ",\n", bindings([E2|Rest]).

name_var(Name=Var) -->
        format_("~w = ~q", [Name,Var]).

format_(Format, Ls) -->
        call(format_codes(Format, Ls)).

format_codes(Format, Ls, Cs0, Cs) :-
        format(codes(Cs0,Cs), Format, Ls).
```

Example:

```
?- repl.
|: X = 4, between(1, 3, Y).
X = 4,
Y = 1
true ;
X = 4,
Y = 2
true ;
X = 4,
Y = 3
true ;
|: X = 7.
X = 7
```

It is easy to modify this so that it works on terms that are specified as *arguments*.

Note that the `variable_names/1` option is essential for reading terms in such a way, and thanks to the ISO standardization effort an increasing number of implementations provide it  for `read_term/2` and related predicates.

This ability to read variable names is a **requirement** for implementing a portable Prolog toplevel!

The main exercise that I leave for you is to check if the *quoting* is right in all cases and (if desired) to produce answers in such a way that they can always be pasted back on the terminal. To extend this to residual **constraints**, use `copy_term/3` and `call_residue_vars/2` to collect pending constraints that you can append to the bindings.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work for something that should work in the first place. What's the point of being able to run queries outside the REPL if you can't get the results of it out of the box?

Comment: Well executing a single goal on the command line is simply different from a REPL, and normally you do not want a REPL interaction when running SWI from a shell script, so there have been only a few instances so far where it would have been worthwhile to factor out the REPL. I agree it should be more modular, and in fact I hope that we can work together on a more modular REPL that would also be useful in other cases where an interaction with the Prolog interpreter takes place! I think getting a basic REPL running is not so hard, and I hope you consider doing this end continue from there.

Comment: Don't forget writing readable variables using the write-option `variable_names/1`!