# Querying prolog dynamically

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there a way of querying a prolog knowledge base dynamically?

I have the prolog logic in a file family.pl (an example that I found here http://www.techytalk.info/prolog-programming-gprolog-linux/). Here is its content:

```
mother_child(trude, sally).

father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).

sibling(X, Y)      :- parent_child(Z, X), parent_child(Z, Y).

parent_child(X, Y) :- father_child(X, Y).
parent_child(X, Y) :- mother_child(X, Y).
```

I want to be able to make queries without getting inside the prolog interpreter.

This command does not work for me:

```
swipl -f family.pl -g "father_child(Father, Child)"
```

Thanks

Comment: [Extremely closely related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283454/querying-from-the-terminal-doesnt-print-anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query *does* work: It's just that you do not see the results if you invoke the program in this way.

So, you can **print** the results yourself, using for example:

```
swipl -f family.pl -g "father_child(Father,Child), \
                       portray_clause(father_child(Father, Child))"
```

This yields:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
?-
```

That's of course not *all* there is to it, so you can use `false/0` to force backtracking:

```
swipl -f family.pl -g "father_child(Father,Child), \
                       portray_clause(father_child(Father, Child)), \
                       false"
```

and that yields:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).
?-
```

Use **`-t halt`** to *halt* the program instead of returning to the toplevel:

```
swipl -f family.pl -g "father_child(Father,Child), \
                       portray_clause(father_child(Father, Child)), \
                       false" -t halt
```

And now at last we have:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(tom, erica).
father_child(mike, tom).
```

P.S.: That's a very nice naming convention for predicates!

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. No I can invoke prolog queries from any other programming language. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! Note though that doing it this way has a somewhat...dated flair to it. Nowadays, you can for example implement a REST service in Prolog or use Pengines (HTTP-based communication) so that other programs can easily query the Prolog engine.

Comment: that's awesome. Thanks!